# Match the url or title with the process id of a tab opened in Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, visual-c++, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I am working on a task to get the task and process id associated with a tab opened in Google Chrome. The Chrome task manager lists all the tab and plugin details, something like the following:

```
Task          Memory        CPU         Network     ProcessId
*************************************************************
Browser      104,424K       0            80              4656
Tab:1        30,928K        0             0              6752
Tab:2        18,360K        0             0              4524
```

So, I want to associate a task with pid, something like `Tab 1` with `PID 6752`.
`Tab 2` with `PID 4524`.

Can anyone tell me how this can be done?

I thought of building the chromium project in Windows, and debug the project to find some answers. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What do you need it for? Chrome has an [extension API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/processes) to do it, but **only** for Dev builds. Will that work for you? If you need that in a stable release version, I'm afraid you'll need external tools like log parsing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to compile your own Chromium version, then probably a Dev-build-only extension API will be okay for you, the experimental [`chrome.processes` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/processes).

You can identify the tabs you're interested in with [`chrome.tabs`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) methods and events, and then pass the `tabID` you obtain to `chrome.processes.getProcessIdForTab()`.

---

If you have to use a version of Chrome without this API (e.g. stable), you can *try* to get the information you need simply from [enabling logging](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) and parsing the resulting log file.

Comment: "What do you need it for?"
well I need the process Id associated with a tab or a bunch of tabs to kill them if the process is consuming too much network bandwidth.  I cannot restrict it to dev channel.

Comment: As for the enable logging I followed your link and I think I did all that was asked starting from launching chrome with verbose flag , opening a tab and then going to user directory to look into  chrome_debug.log , but I dint find the data I was looking for....

Comment: and just to make sure I got my problems cleared ...
I can get all the pid for all the tabs in chrome using CreateToolhelp32Snapshot api , but associating this with the tab title is the problem.